# unexpected token " then "

Tags: shell, scripting

Good day.

I am testing shell script over my own debian notebook

```
android-verify.sh: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
android-verify.sh: line 14: `if [[ ! -z $iopt ]] then { wd=$(pwd) basename "$(test -L "$0" && readlink "$0" || echo "$0")" > /tmp/scriptname'
```

I am still new here. Please advised.

When attempt to include `;`

In the following instruction

```
if [[ ! -z $iopt ]]**;** then { wd=$(pwd) basename "$(test -L "$0" && readlink "$0" || echo "$0")" > /tmp/scriptname

scriptname=$(echo -e -n $wd/ && cat /tmp/scriptname); su -c "cp $scriptname /usr/bin/monitor" root && echo "Congratulations! Script Installed, now run monitor Command" || echo$
fi
```

This bash terminal return the following messages

```
android-verify.sh: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
android-verify.sh: line 17: `fi '
```

Comment: The first error was that you need a semicolon (`;`) or newline between the condition and the `then`. You seem to have recognized that.  The second issue is that you have an unmatched opening brace (`{`) in your script.  Possibly the `$` in "`echo$`" was meant to be a closing brace instead, but making it one would not solve the problem.  Instead, just delete the `{` and the `$`.

Comment: I would also add a newline after the `then`, but that's a matter of style, not necessity.

Comment: many thanks for responding. i testing now

Comment: In general, run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix what it finds before asking questions here.

Comment: And don't put `*`s inside code blocks; they make the code no longer valid syntax, and they don't do bolding or other highlighting or formatting as you seem to intend.

Comment: BTW, `su -c "cp $scriptname ..."` has serious security problems. In general you should **never** substitute variables into a position where their values will be parsed as code instead of data. It's far safer, f/e, to run `sudo cp "$scriptname" ...` -- or with bash 5.0+, if you know the shell started by su will also be bash, you can use `su -c "cp ${scriptname@Q} ..."`; `${var@Q}` escapes the contents of `$var` to be `eval`-safe.

Comment: Please have a look at the bash man page: The section titled _Compound Commands_  contains a description of th `if` command.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code rewritten with the changes to solve the problem and make it more readable:

```
if [[ ! -z $iopt ]] ; then
    wd=$(pwd)
    basename "$(test -L "$0" && readlink "$0" || echo "$0")" > /tmp/scriptname
    scriptname=$(echo -e -n $wd/ && cat /tmp/scriptname)
    su -c "cp $scriptname /usr/bin/monitor" root && echo "Congratulations! Script Installed, now run monitor Command" || echo
fi
```

- I reformatted the code to make it more obvious what is happening and also be able to discuss line numbers with you. It also helps to allow the shell to show line numbers in case other errors come up.
- On the first line, you guessed needing a semi-colon before the `then` which was correct.
- On the 2nd line with the `wd` variable, there was no semi-colon before `base` so the `wd` variable would have effectively only been set only for the `base` command and not any later commands.
- On the 5th line with the three echo's, the last one had a '$' that was out of place and would have resulted in an error about the command not existing.

So in summary:

- Consider re-formatting the code to line breaks to help with readability.
- Add the ';' between the `if` test and the `then` statement
- Add a ';' or line break between `wd` and `base`
- Change `echo$` to `echo`

Hope that helps.